# Setter not found when used inside an R package

Tags: r, function, scope, bioinformatics, bioconductor

First time asking here -I will try to do my best-.

I am writing an analysis package using R for which unfortunately I cannot disclose much. The core object that the package is using to get data and store analysis results is generated by the `SpatialFeatureExperiment` package and is of class `SpatialFeatureExperiment` which is effectively an extension from the `SummarizedExperiment` class. This package has a setter named `colData<-`.

Here comes the problem; when I am sourcing my function to my `.Globalenv` everything works fine with no errors. When I am installing/loading my package (which passes R CMD check) and try to test the functions I get the below error:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) :
unable to find an inherited method for function ‘colData<-’ for signature ‘"SpatialFeatureExperiment", "data.frame"’
```

Below is the traceback:

```
5. stop(gettextf("unable to find an inherited method for function %s for signature %s",
   sQuote(fdef@generic), sQuote(cnames)), domain = NA)

4. (function (classes, fdef, mtable)
   {
   methods <- .findInheritedMethods(classes, fdef, mtable)
   if (length(methods) == 1L) ...

3. `colData<-`(`*tmp*`, value = merge(colData(sfe), DataFrame(gtruth),
   by = c("Barcode", "sample_id"), all = TRUE))

2. add.gTruth(sfe, gtruth = gTruth)

1. addPerLocQC(sfe, gTruth = ground_truth, assay = "counts", 2,
   subsets = list(mito = is_mito))
```

At number 3. in the traceback is where the problems pops up.

---

I have tried a few things:

1. Added the `SpatialFeatureExperiment` package in my Dependences inside the `DESCRIPTION` file using roxygen2.
2. Added the `colData<-` function in my `NAMESPACE` using the `` @importFrom SpatialFeatureExperiment `colData<-` ``  tag.
3. Added `` utils::globalVariables(c(`rowData<-`, `colData<-`)) `` in the `R/globals.R` file.
4. Tried to use the setter as `` SpatialFeatureExperiment::`colData<-`(x, value) ``.

Nothing of the above seemed to work. Having in mind the fact that **when I am sourcing my function it works without any problems**, I believe it is a scoping problem but I cannot think of something else to tackle it.

Any suggestions?

I tried to provide as much as possible. If more is required please let me know.

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Without seeing what is in your `spatialfeatureexperiment` package, in particular the DESCRIPTION and NAMESPACE files, it's impossible to advise.   That said, however,  using `library(foo)` sources all functions in that library so your 'sourced' func has to be the same.  Can you clarify which **function** is failing and provide the relevant parts of the source code?